# htaccess: maintain query var if it exists in referring URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to whip up some htaccess rules on my wordpress install so that I can maintain a query variable while the user clicks on links throughout the site.

Essentially, if a user is at example.com/?prop=1 and clicks on a link, if the link was to example.com/posts, it should automatically go to example.com/posts?prop=1. Just check if the referring url has a prop var in it, and if it does append that to the url they're trying to go to.

I have this right now just from my wordpress permalink structure:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I'm trying to add something like this, but it's not working as I want it to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (^|&)prop=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?prop=%2 [L,R]
```

I can't seem to get the HTTP_REFERER rule to work. Should it not be called every time I click on a link while on a url like example.com/?prop=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't seem correct.

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)prop= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \?(prop=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you! This is the closest i've been able to get thus far! it now properly appends the query var to the new url, but unfortunately causes a redirect loop and won't load the page. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: incredible. the only place this doesn't work is when clicking on a link to the root domain. clicking on a link from example.com/posts/?prop=1 to example.com doesn't keep the query var. but it does with any other link though!

Comment: I feel like this is because the root in wordpress has to actually call index.php and that is confusing the rules?

Comment: awesome that worked. can I ask what exactly the change was so I know going forward? thank you!

Comment: Earlier I was matching `.+` which will of course not work for landing page. Now I have `.*` to make sure it works for landing page also.

Comment: Also if it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.